# Surface Pro 1 Overheating with 16.04

Tags: drivers, overheating, touchscreen

I bought a Surface Pro 1 on Ebay. I am using it for ROS but I am going overseas and needed something to do so I installed Civ V. I know that the surface can handle the game on the lowest setting since my roommate played it on his surface pro 1 for about 6 hours. when I first ran the game, the surface quickly got hot in about ten minutes. I checked the CPU usage and it was near 95%. My initial thoughts was that it had something to do with windows hardware not running windows OS. It is not dual booted since the surface came with a Chinese version of Windows 8 (there was no way to change the language settings). It only has Ubuntu 16.04.

The next day, I watched about 20 min. of a movie before it started to get uncomfortably hot. To get the temperature i used:

```
sensors
```

I ran Civ V in the background again after setting ti the use "Processor microcode firmware for intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)" under the additional drivers setting.

Some specs:

Surface Pro 1
i5 3317u

4 GB RAM

128GB SSD

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I've been looking around for solutions to the heating issue. I have not found much. the little I did was tried above. I'm wanting to know if it is a hardware and/or software issue so that I can return it if need be.

Answer (score 0):

The intel-microcode package version 3.20151106.1 and later have the latest revision of the microcode for the Surface 1 (Intel Ivybridge-U, CPUID 0x306A9). If you installed that package and rebooted, your problem should not be the microcode.  Ensure */proc/cpuinfo* reports a microcode of **0x1c** or higher.

For optimal *thermal* management on that box, you also need the embedded GPU to run with very aggressive thermal management (i.e. *not* at performance mode).

Please try to install "powerd" (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/powerd), it might help.  Also, look for ways to configure the GPU to run at a lower power point, e.g. by downclocking it.